# How to represent C# byte in Typescript

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, byte

I have a c# class that has one property defined as nullable byte. How would I define that in a TypeScript Interface that I'm using in Angualar 9? The property looks like this:

```
public byte? CrawfordStatus { get; set; }
```

Comment: How about `crawfordStatus?: number;`?

Comment: I will try that.. I'm not sure how many bytes a Typescript number takes or how strict the type checking is when I use it in a post or put back to an DotNet Core MVC Controller where the class is defined in c#. The challenge is getting TypeScript Classes or Interfaces communicating with C# classes on the backend.

Comment: You could write out a big long type definition. `type byte = 0|1|2|3|4|...|254|255` but that's it unless this proposal ever gets implemented https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15480